# How to get Leaflet Easy Button (plugin) buttons to display on map?

Tags: leaflet

I am new to Leaflet and JavaScript. I am trying to create a web map that will have 3-4 buttons that when clicked will zoom the user to the given location. Ex: Disney World (28.385384005128767, -81.56313371302178), Black Pool Pleasure Beach (53.937909193096296, -3.0415772052368952).
So far, I have been trying code from a tutorial, but cannot get the buttons to show on my map. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.full {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.full html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
} 

html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
}


#map{ width: 100%; height: 100%; }

iframe{
align-content: center;
width: 98%; height: 97%;
}

.leaflet-bar button,
.leaflet-bar button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.leaflet-bar button {
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.leaflet-bar button:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.leaflet-bar button:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.leaflet-bar button:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.leaflet-bar.disabled,
.leaflet-bar button.disabled {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .4;
}

.easy-button-button .button-state{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}


.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">


</head>
<body id ="full" class= "full">

<div id = "text">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>

    <script>

 var map = L.map('map',{ center: [42.353770, -71.10360608], zoom: 16, keyboard: true});
    
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap' }).addTo(map);

var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
}).addTo(map);    

var OSM = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '© OpenStreetMap' }).addTo(map);

var mapChoices = {
"Satellite": Esri_WorldImagery,
"OSM": OSM
}

    L.control.layers(mapChoices).addTo(map);
    
</script>

<script>

var map = L.map('map', {scrollWheelZoom: false}).setView([37.8, -96], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(zoomTo);

L.easyButton( 'fa-gbp', function(){
  map.setView([55, -2], 4);
}).addTo(map);

L.easyButton( 'fa-jpy', function(){
map.setView([38, 139], 4);
}).addTo(map);

L.easyButton( 'fa-usd', function(){
 map.setView([37.8, -96], 3);
}).addTo(map);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do not re-instantiate your map and do not re-assign your `map` variable.

You can merge your 2 `<script>` tags together, it should become more obvious to you what the issue is.

Your 2nd map instantiation should throw an error in your browser Devtools console (if you are not using it, make sure to learn how to open it)

After that the rest of your script is ignored.